# How do Reducers aggregate the output from all the reducers and produce the final output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

When there are multiple reducers in a Map Reduce code, they do not have any kind of communication between them. But when performing an operation like aggregation all the reducers together produce a single final output. How does the aggregation happen when there is no communication between them? Is it by writing to the context?(context.write())

Answer (score 0):

If you set the number of reduce tasks to 1 (which is also the default value), then all the reduce() methods are run by the same task, so no communication is needed.

If you set the number of reduce tasks to *n*, then you will have *n* output files, not just 1. Those results are indeed independent. Perhaps, you should specify what you mean by "aggregation".

Comment: Thanks for the response @vefthym. I understand that there would be as many part files as the number of reducers. But my question was the logic or the operation performed will be on all the reducers and there will be only one output for all these and not a local result per reducer(which a combiner does). Does that clarify my question?

Comment: @spark_dream No, it doesn't. Each of reducers is working independently, processes independent set of keys (governed by Partitioner) and has its own independent output path in HDFS. So, I don't understand what you mean by term "aggregation".

Comment: @gudok Let me make it more clear. For example if my usecase was to find the total number of words in a given text file(not the individual count for each word) how could a MapReduce Job do this?

Comment: @spark_dream Pure map-reduce approach is to stream all data through single reducer. You will need to write map and combiner in such way that each combiner produces single key/value pair: `{NullWriteable(), LongWriteable(num of words from this mapper)}`. All such key/value pairs go into single reducer which sums values and writes result into part-00000 file.

Comment: So is it that there will not be any need that we need to perform some operation on 2 or more keys in 2 or more different reducers and aggregate their values? (As all the values for the same key go to the same reducer and there might be more than one key per reducer. )